# Google Analytics, Tracking a non-ad network ad

Tags: drupal-6, google-analytics

My website is a small website meant for purely local use and I do not advertise with any network. I contact local businesses manually and get advertisements from them.

I have set up the ads to act as a rotating banner where the trigger to change is based on a page refresh. I want to provide my advertisers with metrics displaying the performance of their advertisement. How can I track each ad (which is essentially an image) for # of impressions and click through rates?

I`m using Drupal 6 if that is relevant.

Comment: You may want to look at something google dfp for this. You can roll your own system, but it will take some custom development.

Comment: DFP pricing might be a bit steep for small users (and Doubleclick is not really interessted in small clients).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Use Events, for onclick and onload:

```
<a href="http://localhost/someurl" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'Click', 'BANNERNAME',1.00,true]);" > <img style="border: 0px" src="http://localhost/someurltoapic.jpg" alt="SOMEALTEXT" /></a>
<img width=0 height=0 src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'Impression', 'BANNERNAME',2.00,true]);"/></a>
```

I have written a detailed solution over here :http://www.statstory.com/tracking-clicks-and-impressions-in-google-analytics/ which also includes a script for ad rotation as well.